# Rename Android project name in Eclipse did not update "launching name"

Tags: android, eclipse

I renamed my Android project in Eclipse with this method: right click on the project -> refactor -> rename. Everything seems to be working fine, however in one place I still see old name. Please take a look at the picture http://postimg.org/image/rac8relc5/. In the bottom right corner you can see: launching 5 (5 is old name). I cleaned my project, restarted Eclipse, restarted my computer but it does not help. In my file project.properties there is no name defined. How can I change this old name in this place? Or at least why it was not changed.

Comment: Has your Manifest been updated/refactored?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I remove content of bin directory and build solution (If you mean file in bin). In manifest I have defined name with string resource.

Answer (score 1):

try to:

Edit res/values/strings.xml of your project and change the value of app_name to whatever you want to renamed 
    in Refactor.

Comment: In file strings.xml I have different name defined than in app_name. There is no problem here.

Comment: create a new project and copy all the files is a solution, hope it helps mate

Comment: Sure, it will solve the problem. But now I am just curious where Eclipse saved this old name.

Comment: maybe it saves it once when the project is created the first time, I recommend you to use Android Studio mate